# How to change width of last column in Finder

Tags: macos, finder

Near the bottom of each divider between columns in Finder there are two little horizontal bars that when clicked and dragged resizes the column to the left. This is great, but since the last column doesn't have a divider to the right of it, how can it be resized?

Answer (score 3):

The last column isn't actually a column, strictly speaking, it's a preview.

The only way to resize it is to enlarge the overall window, which can be a bit irritating if you are a lot of levels deep…

[image]

You can try Alt/dragging one of the columns smaller, which will change all of them. Then, allowing for a bit of a screen bug which means you need to change the window size slightly, you can gain as much room as possible for the final column/preview

Graphics glitch/screen bug …

[image]

Comment: I already have the window at the full width of the screen. There are enough levels that there's a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: I added the alt-drag trick, which may help

Answer (score 0):

Make the Finder window larger than the sum of the column width, and you will get a bar you can drag to resize.

Using the example image below, this was achieved by grabbing the resize bar between "Size" and "Kind" and shrinking the Size column just a tad. 
This allows you to expand the "Kind" column.

[image: After resizing between "Size" and "Kind"]

Comment: You never get a resizer on the last column.

Comment: Which version of OS X?

Comment: Any I can remember, up to & including El Capitan.

Comment: See edit - just got to a computer to experiment a bit.  Just saw your answer, basically the same idea.

Comment: Pictures would be good, because I can't actually grok quite what you mean [other than if you're talking about the graphics glitch I mentioned in my edit - which is not draggable]

Comment: Yea sorry, I tend to be a bit rushed for pics.  But I think we're basically on the same page - gave you the +1 :)

Comment: And.....just realized I was thinking list view this whole time...